# How to make a general modal dialog service for opening confirm dialogs?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

What would be the best way to implement a general Angular 2+ (v5 in my app) service for opening a BootstrapV4 modal with ngx-bootstrap?

I need a general modal dialog which can take a string Input (title of a model) and EventEmitter Output (with a boolean value) that can be used for confirmation of deleting an item and I do not want to create a new dialog every time this pattern occur.

I know how to use the BsModalService for opening a modal from a component, but how can I make it reusable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you can build this service on top of BsModalService.

Examples:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#confirm-window

Comment: That worked perfectly - I had missed the service-component guide when I searched for a solution :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this component: [ngx-modal-dialog](https://github.com/Greentube/ngx-modal). It's css framework agnostic, so you can easily use it with bootstrap or something else. It supports:

- creation via service
- single instance check
- passing in custom title, content component and/or action buttons

Check this page for (kinda) demo: [Modal dialog demo](https://meeroslav.github.io/angular-seed/misc)

Comment: Repo is dead as of 2023

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I had no time to continue maintaining it. Feel free to fork it and continue the work.